# Reactor compose vs flatMap

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

I continue playing with Reactor, and now I see `compose` operator that behave exactly like `flatMap` and I´m wondering if there´s any difference that I don't understand.

```
    @Test
public void compose() throws InterruptedException {
    Scheduler mainThread = Schedulers.single();
    Flux.just(("old element"))
            .compose(element ->
                    Flux.just("new element in new thread")
                            .subscribeOn(mainThread)
                            .doOnNext(value -> System.out.println("Thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getName())))
            .doOnNext(value -> System.out.println("Thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}

@Test
public void flatMapVsCompose() throws InterruptedException {
    Scheduler mainThread = Schedulers.single();
    Flux.just(("old element"))
            .flatMap(element ->
                    Flux.just("new element in new thread")
                            .subscribeOn(mainThread)
                            .doOnNext(value -> System.out.println("Thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getName())))
            .doOnNext(value -> System.out.println("Thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

This two examples behave and return the same result.

Regards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[An excellent explanation by Dan Lew](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/03/02/dont-break-the-chain/):

The difference is that `compose()` is a higher level abstraction: it operates on the entire stream, not individually emitted items. In more specific terms:

- `compose()` is the only way to get the original `Observable<T>` from the stream. Therefore, operators that affect the whole stream (like `subscribeOn()` and `observeOn()`) need to use `compose()`.

  In contrast, if you put `subscribeOn()`/`observeOn()` in `flatMap()`, it would only affect the `Observable` you create in `flatMap()` but not the rest of the stream.
- `compose()` executes immediately when you create the `Observable` stream, as if you had written the operators inline. `flatMap()` executes when its `onNext()` is called, each time it is called. In other words, `flatMap()` transforms each item, whereas `compose()` transforms the whole stream.
- `flatMap()` is necessarily less efficient because it has to create a new `Observable` every time `onNext()` is called. `compose()` operates on the stream as it is. If you want to replace some operators with reusable code, use `compose()`. `flatMap()` has many uses but this is not one of them.

Comment: I update my question. I dont understand then why If I execute the two examples both are executed in the same threads. I understood that the sibscribeOn it should only affect the Flux inside the flatMap

Comment: @paul, `single()` returns a default, shared, **single-thread-backed** `Scheduler` instance

Comment: With all types of Schedulers I receive the same result. I dont know if I´m doing something wrong here.

Comment: To see run the thread out of the flatMap in another thread. And in the compose in the same one. No worries, with the second response is now 100%’clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Explanation from @Andrew is pretty good. Just wanted to add an example for better understanding.

```
Flux.just("1", "2")
        .compose( stringFlux -> {
            System.out.println("In compose"); // It takes whe whole Flux as input
           return stringFlux.collectList();
        }).subscribe(System.out::println);


Flux.just("1", "2").flatMap(s -> { //Input to the anonymous function is individual items in stream
            System.out.println("In flatMap");
            return Flux.just(Integer.parseInt(s));
        }).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

This produces the output

```
In compose
[1, 2]
In flatMap
1
In flatMap
2
```

Which indicates `compose` works on entire stream but `flatMap` works on individual items in the stream